# Failed to build python app in Heroku; can't find newscatcher

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, pip

In trying to push to heroku I am getting a "build failed" error.

In checking the logs I see it's because of the following:

```
       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement newscatcher==0.1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3ad91c7bdb0b7ae3e65e7d3b8ae455f7/requirements.txt (line 13)) (from versions: none)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for newscatcher==0.1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3ad91c7bdb0b7ae3e65e7d3b8ae455f7/requirements.txt (line 13))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

It looks like there's an incorrect version of the "newscatcher" library I am trying to use. However, this is the correct version according to PyPi.

In addition I have already performed a `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` in order to collect all dependencies I know to be relevant. How come the correct version of a git supported pip package is throwing this error? How do I fix this?

Comment: [`newscatcher` 0.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/newscatcher/0.1.0/) requires Python >= 3.7 that is 3.7 or 3.8. What Python have you configured for the application at Heroku?

Comment: Python 3.7 is the python I'm using